# How can I trigger a CellPaint event in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net

I want to make an application that fills each cell of a table layout as I click a button. I tried to call `CellPaint`, but it doesn't work. I found that Sub runs only one time as Form starts.

```
Call TableLayoutPanel1_CellPaint()
```

Please tell me how to call `CellPaint` so that I can change color of cell that I selected.

```
Private Sub TableLayoutPanel1_CellPaint(sender As Object, e As TableLayoutCellPaintEventArgs) Handles TableLayoutPanel1.CellPaint
    paletteColumn = 0
    If e.Row = canvasCellLocation(0) Then
        If e.Column = canvasCellLocation(1) Then
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(C(paletteColumn), e.CellBounds)
            MessageBox.Show(paletteColumn)
        End If
    End If
```

Comment: VB.NET IsNot VBA and IsNot VB6 - the tags have text that provides guidance.  In Windows, you dont "call" events, especially Paint. It is invoked as parts of the screen need repainting.  And dont use a messagebox in the paint event, it will liekly result in another paint event needed.  Use the output window for debugging

Comment: Thanks for guidance. So there isn't any way to color some cell when I want? Isn't there alternative stuffs? Plz Help...

Comment: `myTableLayoutPanel.Invalidate(myCellRect, True)`

Comment: Thank You! All of my Question are Solved!